# How to configure Apache to forward a PUT request to GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I hope I am barking up the right tree here. We implemented a PHP-based REST api which among others uses a PUT. On some servers the PUT request is being converted to a GET. Locally, we don't have a server that does that, however some of our customers are reporting the problem.

We want to configure our server as such so that we can reproduce and provide a solution. My thinking is that this can be done through the Apache config or through some .htaccess directive, but I have not been able to find the right setup.

I have used the Limit directive, but this provides a 403 - Forbidden message. I want the request to go through, but instead of a PUT it should be changed to a GET.

**Limit example**

```
<Limit GET POST HEAD OPTIONS>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all  
</Limit>     
<LimitExcept GET POST HEAD OPTIONS>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all   
</LimitExcept>
```

Should I be using a Rewrite instead? If so, what is the syntax to use?

Thanks

P.S.
I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206521/why-does-my-put-http-request-get-converted-to-a-get), asking why the PUT is being converted to a GET. That question also provides additional details of my situation.